# Destroy session variables on clicking logout from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I am using a header across multiple pages. I have a drop menu from which a user can select to log out. On clicking log out I want to destroy the session variables.

How can I run PHP when log out has been clicked in the drop down menu?

Here's my drop down menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">  
    <li><a href="#">Register User</a></li>
    <li><a href=#">View Access List</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: It's already running. The code in `logout.php` will be invoked when the browser requests that page.

Comment: session_destroy(); in logout.php and make it redirect to your main file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run your PHP in an onclick because when PHP is rendered it doesn't look for the events in which it is called instead it just goes for the execution and performs the action it has been told to do. So running a `session_destroy()` in the `onclick` event would just not wait for a click but when the page will be loaded it would destroy the session. Try making another PHP file and then link the logout link to that page then perform you PHP there then use the `header()` function to redirect a page to another page.

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 4):

if you have several user its better to save user's id before destroy session:

```
session_start();
$id = $session['User_id'];//user have user_id attribute
unset($_SESSION);

header("Location:index.php?message=logout?id=$id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You set your `logout.php` to something like:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();

    header("Location:index.php?message=logout");

?>
```

It's a simple example but you can enhance it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your `logout.php` file must include:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy(); // ALL sessions of your site will be destoryed
    header("location: index.php?do=logout"); // or where ever you want to redirect the user
?>
```